# Changing width & centering Wordpress horizontal menu items

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, width, center

I am currently working on the following Wordpress site:

http://2013.whitehallrow.com/

It's obvious that the horizontal menu items are not styled properly. I want the "Media" link to fit on the right side of the navbar; how do I go about changing the width of each item so that they will all fit?

I also want the menu items to be centered, so that the margins on each side are equal. My knowledge of the existing Wordpress theme's CSS is sketchy; could anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with CSS because browser simply cannot know what the widths of the items are going to be. One solution is to hard-code the margins individually. Other solution is to use Javascript. Personally, I would go with the former. If you go with the latter, you will see the menu "flicker" every time a page loads and everyone hates that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little "dirty", because it is specific for your menu and for names that have been included in it. But maybe is useful:

```
.main-navigation li {
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}

/* For the distance of the first element */
main-navigation li:first-child {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

/* For nulling the distance of the first child element */
.menu-item-type-post_type li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: The code for fitting the menu items on the same line works like a charm, but when I use margin-left on the first-child, it also pushes forward the first item in each drop-down menu. Is there a way to select only the first child in the immediate menu, not the submenus?

Comment: Simply changing ".main-navigation li:first-child" to ".menu-item-type-post_type li:first-child".

Comment: That made ONLY the submenus' first item move right, and the nav links are back to the way they were before...

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right. Check now, this should work correctly.

Comment: YES! Worked perfectly. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that.

Look in menu css file and find `.your_menu_name li a` section. Here look for **padding** and just adjust size.

For ex. if is `padding-left:30px;` replace `30` with `10` and see you working menu.

You can customize to by adding hover condition like `background-color:#CCCCCC;`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can select each menu item by using CSS3 pseudo class `:nth-child(N)`, refer [this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild). Eg.:

   ```
   .nav-menu li:nth-child(3) {
       display: block;
       width: 300px; /*Your individual menu-item width here*/
   }
   ```
2. To align your menu to center you have to change your css in `style.css` (line no: 1460) to following

   ```
   .main-navigation ul.nav-menu, .main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
       border-bottom: 1px solid #8293FF;
       border-top: 1px solid #8293FF;
       display: table;
       text-align: center;
       width: 100%;
   }
   ```